# How many ways do we need to remember how big an integer is?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, needs-more-focus

Consider this question:  [What is the maximum value for an int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-an-int32)

I know it was created in the dark-ages of Stack Overflow, but this should have been trivial to look up in any of your preferred documentation sources.  As for the second part of the question, asking for a way to remember it is far too broad for the current Stack Overflow scope.

Some of the answers (both deleted and undeleted) are downright nonsense as well.  Do we really need 74 different answers on how to remember how big an integer is?

I feel that the question is way too broad as is (and I voted to close as such, but the close vote fell off without any further votes). Is there any value in this question any more?

Should this question be closed/deleted/locked?

Comment: It should be closed and deleted, but it'll probably be closed and historically locked.

Comment: It was closed once it seems. It's not clear to me why it was reopened the next day

Comment: We need to be reminded in (2^32)/2 different ways.

Comment: It was reopened by a former SE employee.

Comment: It may not be SO by roles but it is the first time I'm seeing it and it is hilarious

Comment: @dWinder Well it's fun but [we do hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) around here.

Comment: @yivi You mean ((2^32)/2)-1 ways, no?  We wouldn't want to overflow after all.

Comment: I wish, @Servy. But I have a lousy memory. That -1 would screw things up for me.

Comment: @Servy Of course we don't want `-1`... it's not called Stack**overflow** for nothing!

Comment: @TripeHound The site is Stack Overflow, not Integer Overflow

Comment: @Servy having that many integers would certainly produce a stack of sorts.

Comment: And it's already got two reopen votes again, so clearly something more permanent needs to be done.

Comment: A one-line-joke-answer with 5k upvotes. Seeing that is somewhat frustrating. At least frustrating enough to say that I wouldn't mind if you burned this specific Q/A to the ground. With fire :-/

Comment: Can someone please mark this as [status-completed]? A historical lock was added.

Comment: I'm disappointed the question has been locked. I can no longer enjoy bestowing upvotes on all the wittiness. EDIT: Ah thank goodness, I can at least favourite the question.

Comment: This is a very relevant question. It capture the essence of the differences between computers and humans. Please don't delete it. I still need this, since I can't remember the number still today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I can never remember the number. I need a memory rule.

If this was posted now, it would be downvoted to oblivion, making it the top downvoted answer of the day, would trigger an avalanche of "unfriendly" comments, then closed as "too broad".

Given the high number of views, deleting is clearly not an option. I've cleaned up some recent answers which added to the noise, now I think it's time for historical lock, (but not before I add *my* python answer):

```
(1<<31) - 1
```

Comment: In what type of variable do you hope the computer will store the `(1<<31)` before it can subtract the 1? Does the result need casting to an int32? ;)

Comment: I'm sticking to a python solution precisely to avoid those C quirks :)

Comment: While I agree on what you said here, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56958719/3182664 is (of all the answers that I've seen there) the **only** one that really makes sense (especially with the new question title). Why did you delete it, or what do you think about undeleting it?

Comment: How can a python count that high? It has no fingers or toes!

Comment: It's unlikely that Python will compile where that expression won't work as C. :)  In terms of actual portability, is at least as portable C as it is Python.

Comment: Can we edit the title to "How can I remember the maximum value for an int32?"? That's what most of the answers are about.

Comment: @Dukeling NO, that makes the question even worse. It's bad enough that the answers have answered that phrase, but we definitely don't need the title to be edited to make the question even more off-topic. Jean, please change it back.

Comment: okay, reverted to the revision 2 title. Now question looks like when it was posted. Makes sense as it is "historical"

Comment: @CodeCaster If we want it to be a reference post for "what's the maximum value", we should probably delete all answers about how to remember it (i.e. most answers). If we want to keep the answers, we should probably change the title to reflect what they're actually answering. Yes, the question they're actually answering is off topic and too broad, but that's why we're locking it. It being locked doesn't stop it from showing up in Google searches, so the title should reflect the content of the question and answers.

Comment: The question looks a bit weird with both the lock banner **and** the closed banner. I can't see any answers before the page fold. It's annoying. Seeing as the lock is sufficient to prevent people from making the question any worse, can you re-open it while keeping it locked?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: ?? Why did you change it from _"an int32"_ to _"a int32"_?? Why change it from correct to incorrect? It feels like you did this to annoy me for the rest of eternity, since I can't edit the post :| I don't know French (much) but in English the rule is _if the following word begins with a consonant sound, use "a", if it begins with a vowel sound, use "an"_. I'm annoyed now. Humph. Might have to run for moderator next election so I can fix this crime against English grammar.

Comment: @Clonkex we always need new fantastic moderators. But feel free to start by collecting the badges [Marshal] and [Steward] and [discussion], because without them, you're unlikely to be a good candidate. Also, you'll be able to correct my double `and` in my comment once you're a moderator!

Comment: Note: In C, `1<<31` is _integer overflow_ and so _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @Clonkex sorry, reverted the question title. I didn't write that myself, must be the title of revision 2 or 3. BTW you can run for moderator, but not for the wrong reasons :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Don't worry, running for mod was a joke. I don't have nearly enough time to do mod duties right now :)

Answer (score 25):

The question is too broad by SO's current standards. There are a lot of answers on there that can be considered "Valid", as every language out there has their own name for the relevant constant.

*"How do you remember <large number>"* isn't very specific, or necessarily programming related.

In my opinion, this should be closed as *"too broad"* (as it is now), and probably locked for historical significance.

Comment: The question has exactly one, verifyable answer. _"What is the maximum value a four-byte (32-bit) signed integer can hold?"_, with the additional complaint _"I can't remember it"_. The complaint is not the question, the question is in the title. So I don't see how it's too broad. The question isn't the problem, the nonsense answers are. There's a reason it has one point five million views, and the accepted answer has five thousand upvotes. It probably was the top Google result for that question for very long.

Comment: _"I need a memory rule."_ is also in the question. That's too broad. While the title is important, we can't ignore the question's body.

Comment: That's just noise. A complaint. Filler, something to give the question a body. The OP didn't accept a mnemonic or other memory rule, they accepted the answer containing just the number. If you don't like the noise (I for one don't), the question needs editing.

Comment: We can't speak for the OP there. Maybe he accepted that answer because of the silly amount of upvotes it got. We don't know. I don't agree with your assertion that the question's __body__ is noise.

Comment: @CodeCaster When removing the off-topic part of a question invalidates like 50 answers, it's probably fair to say the question is beyond salvageable and should just be closed, locked and/or deleted.

Comment: @Dukeling and that's why I'm telling it needs a lock. It has 1.5 million views, it is the #2 Google result for me for "max value of int32". And perhaps some of the more recent answers should be deleted.

Comment: I'm not arguing for a deletion, by the way. A lock sounds good to me, on top of the closure. That sends the signal that questions like these are no longer on-topic, while preserving the historical significance, google result, and sparing the author of that answer any more silly edits.

Comment: Why bother locking it for historical significance? A quick Google search gives the answer right away and the content provided is mostly useless. Just delete it. ("max value of int32" gives the number as the first result)

Comment: @JL2210 Every deletion of an old post has a cost in terms of link rot. While the cost is sometimes negligible, it presumably isn't in the case of a question with a million and a half views. That being so, the question would have to be causing a lot of harm to justify deletion. I don't think that is the case here.

Comment: Should be deleted that question ! I found nothing help ....

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for being the only person to speak up for the question, other than its 1300 upvoters. I hate the current community in charge of Stack Overflow for invalidating all the good questions, and they overrun meta so I can't even upvote anything to show that I disagree, because no one is speaking for me.

Comment: @Noumenon: if the majority, including the moderators, disagree with you, could it be that you’re wrong?

Comment: @Cerbrus I can't be wrong about how I feel! I agree in theory that the minority of  answerers/moderators deserves to rule the site. It's just that they use up all their goodwill by closing useful questions against the will of the voters.

Comment: @Noumenon: _”closing useful questions against the will of the voters”_? How? If those voters are upvoting the question, they can also re-oprn vote it. Maybe those questions weren’t that useful.

Comment: @Cerbrus You've forgotten what it's like to be average. Since reopening takes 3000 rep, it is not available to the voters. My complaint is that the 3000-plus rep crowd doesn't care about how most people feel.

Comment: Close-votes also require 3000 rep, @Noumenon. That cancels each other out. We don’t care about how people feel, no, we care about the quality of the site’s contents.

Comment: Privileges held only by a minority don't cancel each other out! That's like saying it's fine that blacks can't vote against Jim Crow because whites have the right to vote against Jim Crow. I'm not even saying you're doing a bad job with the quality of the site. I just hate being disregarded. I'm sorry, you can move this all to chat or delete it.

Answer (score 4):

It's a question that's a couple of months younger than the site is, when the rules were more lax. Besides that, it's an on-topic programming question (the fact that something can be looked up in documentation never made a question off-topic).

However, if you look at the question, you'll see that nonsensical answers are added up till this month. **That** needs to be prevented. So it needs a lock of some sort, so no more nonsense answers will be added.

<sub>Retained so the comments below still make sense: between you asking this question and me posting this answer, hundreds of off-topic or duplicate questions have been asked. Go and close them, don't go digging for old dirt that doesn't need any more attention.</sub>

Comment: `Go and close them, don't go digging for old dirt that doesn't need any more attention.`  Sure, let's just leave broken windows broken.  Fun fact:  I wasn't even digging, I actually came across it in the Active question list, because someone edited an answer and bumped it back into Active.  Why was I in the Active questions section?  Looking for off-topic questions.

Comment: But that wasn't mentioned in your question. When changing the sort order of the answers, I noticed it still received a couple of nonsensical answers this year, so it needs to be locked, but nothing more. I feel it's on-topic, but the latest answers aren't.

Comment: It's not relevant how or why the OP found this question. Judge the question on it's own (lack of) merits, not on the circumstances in which it was found.

Comment: @Cerbrus and I'm saying, with this answer, that I don't think this question deserves any more attention than a lock. It's not off-topic.

Comment: And you may have a valid point, but it's been lost in your condescending tone.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Then I'd suggest removing the second paragraph in this answer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that may be, but that's exactly the sentiment I want to carry across. I loathe questions like this, singling out a single, irrelevant, non-problem-causing question, and as such I also despise tag burnination requests. I find it nitpicky and "mopping with the tap open". There's **so** much more (and much more important) work to be done, being: closing recently asked, off-topic questions, but that just doesn't happen.

Comment: It cannot be deleted anyway, only a moderate is able to do that since the question has many upvotes

Comment: You probably don't want to look at my question history on Meta then :D

Comment: @CodeCaster: Please don't let your personal grudges cloud your judgement...

Comment: That some arguably less important work gets done doesn't preclude that other, arguably more important work gets done at the same time (by the same, or by other  users).

Comment: @yivi false. The amount of work that can be executed is finite. The people who read, answered and commented here could've collectively closed tens of questions in the past thirty minutes. However, we chose to bicker here.

Comment: @CodeCaster “If people are trying to bring you down it only means that you are above them.”  I support you!

Comment: @PeterHaddad That's not true; after it was closed for 2 days, anyone with 10k rep can vote to delete it. It would take 10 votes to remove it. (It would probably be more helpful to reach some sort of consensus here and then have a mod carry it out IMO.)

Comment: @PeterHaddad: That's the kind of logic a dictator would support ;-)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I meant now, 10 days from now it would be reopened

Comment: @PeterHaddad I see. Well let's just hope we reach some sort of consensus here so we can take the easy mod path.

Comment: The only reason we "waste" time on these things, is because not everybody agrees on everything. If nobody showed up to defend posts some other users feel are crap, we could get rid off them in a couple minutes and get back to the usual business. But logically we want for everybody to have their say so we can form some sort of consensus. You may feel this is "bickering", but you seem quite invested IMO.

Comment: ....and it is closed now.. will probably get opened later again

Comment: No, it's locked now, @PeterHaddad

Comment: @Cerbrus when I wrote my comment it was not locked :p